# Ionic framework - Angular: include libraries in my html code is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developping an hybride App using Ionic and Angular and I tried to include jquery UI for dragging service but it didn't work for me I tried simple examples to see if it works but it didn't. Here is my code

```html
<ion-view view-title="{{vm.title}}" class="exlhoist-dashboard-view">

  <ion-content
    has-bouncing="true"
    padding="true"
    scroll="true">
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p>Drag me</p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
      });
    </script>
  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Jquery package? sometime without installing the package you may get these errors.
Steps for installing Jquery
1. First, install the package

```
npm install jquery --save
```

2. Install the typing files

   npm install -g typings

   typings install dt~jquery --global --save
3. Import the file to your project

> import * as $ from 'jquery'

Comment: How to import the file ? I mean where I put " import * as $ from 'jquery' " ?

Comment: my code doesn't support this "import" here is a snippet of my code :

'use strict';
module.exports = angular
  .module('app.dashboard.controller', ['ngTouch'])
  .controller('appDashboard', appDashboard)
...

Comment: Then I better suggest reinstall the whole package